# Not able to make inventory of the store

Tags: c++, vector

Store.cpp:

```
table[plu_code] = new Product(plu_code, name, sold_by_weight, price, inv);//This will call look up table operator '[]'
num_products++; // counting number of items in inventory
```

LookupTable.h:

```
private:
T *aptr[MAXRANGE];
int rangeStart[MAXRANGE];
int rangeEnd[MAXRANGE];
int numRanges;
T defaultValue; //needed to return when [] operator does not find valid product


T &LookupTable<T>::operator[](int value)
{ 
// find the range
if (value>0 && value<9999) //inorganic tems
    return aptr[0][value-rangeStart[0]];
else if (value>90000 && value<99999)//organic items
    return aptr[1][value - rangeStart[1]];
else
    return defaultValue;
}
```

The problem is when pointer is returned, it cannot assign address to the product object.[image]

Comment: Not able to make sense of your question

Comment: I am trying to return the pointer and then assign the Product Object. But after debugging, it is shown that there is no object field in the pointer/table[plu_code]